# SQL Server 2008: how to write query for multiple columns in select and in group by only 1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My requirement is how to write a query for multiple columns in select and in group by only 1 column. In this multiple columns of select, the first column i have used distinct. But I want to group by only one column that is the 3rd column. Please tell me any one.

I am getting result like this:

```
D2A08528-FFBA-492D-AF51-50D6CC10C5A4    b.vithoban@gmail.com    E0F127ED-DA67-45F4-A2C5-C0E89CB5E1B4    5
6110E173-419B-4C1B-8524-6D9EF39D27E7    bonthapally123@gmail.com    E0F127ED-DA67-45F4-A2C5-C0E89CB5E1B4    5
52D7DA02-9415-447F-9DF4-8D327E599347    rama6452@gmail.com  E0F127ED-DA67-45F4-A2C5-C0E89CB5E1B4    5
9FCC3C51-3BB7-4A18-A1E5-9B4C6B657AB2    krishna.rama718@gmail.com   E0F127ED-DA67-45F4-A2C5-C0E89CB5E1B4    5
EB79FC72-5144-445E-8EE7-D3A195902210    venkatanarasaiahmannam@gmail.com    E0F127ED-DA67-45F4-A2C5-C0E89CB5E1B4    5
C04EA2EF-8311-4194-B67D-D88C1CDA912D    ramakrishna2526@gmail.com   E0F127ED-DA67-45F4-A2C5-C0E89CB5E1B4    5
40D24F2E-7D3A-48A8-ADCF-208E2F463C81    sivaputta123@gmail.com  C83583D4-C08A-4AFF-93FB-5FB91654D320    2
DE42D201-7513-43BD-98A1-4F5B52C799A3    bonthapally123@gmail.com    7C6FA760-0B13-4629-9383-C7D943A1DE8C    1
```

But I need the result to look like this:

```
D2A08528-FFBA-492D-AF51-50D6CC10C5A4 b.vithoban@gmail.com E0F127ED-DA67-45F4-A2C5C0E89CB5E1B4   5

40D24F2E-7D3A-48A8-ADCF-208E2F463C81 sivaputta123@gmail.com  C83583D4-C08A-4AFF-93FB-5FB91654D320    2

DE42D201-7513-43BD-98A1-4F5B52C799A3  bonthapally123@gmail.com 7C6FA760-0B13-4629-9383-C7D943A1DE8C   1
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 3rdColumn ORDER BY 3rdColumn) RNum,
        * 
    FROM YourTable
)x WHERE RNum=1
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need should be in @techdo's answer. Here is just a [SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/974d0/5) using @techdo's query.

Comment: If you think the answer is helpful, please select @techno's reply as answer.

Comment: @techdo, you are welcome, don't want to let a good answer be skipped.